# Windows 7 Kernel Is Missing, or Corrupt

Tags: windows-7, ntoskrnl.exe

I had Windows 7 boot issues and I managed to fix them using bootrec. I then restarted my PC to start up windows and I got the options to start windows normally, last known good configuration, or safe mode.

I tried the each option once and every time I got this error:

> file: /Windows/System32/ntoskrnl.exe
>
> status: 0xc0000359
>
> info: Windows failed to load because kernel is missing, or corrupt

I tried to run a *startup repair* and the *workaround 1* solution [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/no-boot-windows-7-error-ntoskrnlexe-is-missing-or/bed3d422-57d2-477e-bc41-db456e9533cf), but nothing worked.

**Any solutions?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[0xc0000359](http://errlookup.azurewebsites.net/?err=0xc0000359) = "STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_WIN_32" -- "The specified image file did not have the correct format"

Most likely you had/have file-system and/or physical disk corruption, and your kernel file(s) is pooched beyond repair.

Scan the HDD for errors and repair them (CHKDSK and the HDD manufacturer's utilities).

If the utilities detect the drive as not repairable, then replace it (and restore from backup or reinstall).

If it says it fixed things, try a Windows Repair again.

If that repair doesn't work, and/or the scan utilities reported the drive as healthy, then the file(s) are damaged beyond repair.  Restore from backup, or reinstall Windows.